# Run commands on the runner directly even if a container is used for GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

Is there a way to use the `run` directly on the runner? I use a container like this:

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: debian:10-slim

    steps:
      - name: Runs on container
        run: |
          ls -l
```

If i would want to use the `gh`command, which is installed on the runner (ubuntu-latest) by default, is there a way to use `run` in this context? Or do i loose all access to the runner if i choose a container?